# Разделение переменной на переменные

Tags: python

Допустим, на вход подается строка: `2 + x = 12`
программа должна разделить это на 4 переменные:

```
first = 2
second = x
third = 12
task = "+"
```

как такое сделать?

Comment: А `=` куда делось? Его нужно не учитывать?

Comment: @Павел, да его надо просто убрать

Comment: Много условий пропущено, зависит сильно от входных данных, все ли ваши строки будут вида `ax + b = c`, или могут быть более сложные уравнения? Или вы просто хотите понять, как можно это реализовать в этом конкретном случае?

Comment: я пытаюсь понять и возможно написать решатель подобных уравнений, уже давно задумываюсь о таком.

Comment: Вообще, для деления строки на блоки используется функция `split()`, можете почитать подробнее [здесь](https://pythonru.com/baza-znanij/razdelit-stroku-split), для базовых знаний это пригодится, а конкретная задача - решатель уравнений, достаточно сложная и проще всего её реализовать при помощи дополнительных библиотек, типа `numpy`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать *регулярные выражения* для вашей задачи (или нет - см. примечание в конце):

```
import re

inp = "2 + x = 12"     # или  inp = input()  для ввода из консоли
first, task, second, __, third = re.split(r"\s+", inp)

first = int(first)
third = int(third)
```

---

После этого кода будут значения переменных такие:

> ```
> first = 2
> second = "x"
> third = 12
> task = "+"
> ```

---

Объяснение:

1. Функция `split()` модуля `re` (т.е. `re.split()`) принимает как первый параметр *регулярное выражение*, для которого второй параметр будет делиться на части.

   В регулярном выражении `r"\s+"`:

   - `\s` значит пробел (space) или табулятор (или другой пустой символ),
   - `+` значит, что такой символ может повториться.

   Значит, строка `inp` будет делиться на основании присутствия подстрок из пустых символов.
2. Таким образом, результатом использования функции `re.split()` будет список

   > ```
   > ["2", "+", "x", "=", "12"]
   > ```

   из которого вытащим отдельные элементы так называемой *распаковкой* списка:

   ```
   first, task, second, __, third = ...
   ```

   Для ненужного элемента `=` мы использовали (чудесное) имя `__`, чтобы ясно было видеть, что нам его не надо.

---

*Примечание:*

В вашем конкретном случае, когда между отдельными частями находятся только пробелы, возможно обойтись без регулярных выражений (`import re`) а применить только стандартную функцию `split()`:

```
first, task, second, __, third = inp.split()
```